# Sending a DateTime to a SQL Query in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have a stored procedure in my database that has a `DateTime` as a parameter. As far as I am concerned, if I send to the query a `datetime` object, the framework will do the magic (lol).

However, when I run the query I get an exception with the following error message:

> *Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.*

I made a generic method to communicate with the database in which I only tell him the stored procedure name and the parameters.

The `datetime` I am sending from C# is read from the configuration file and converted.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I am using C# with the .NET Framework and using SQL SERVER 2008 for the DataBase.

I get the date from the configuration file like this:

```
DateTime fechaSistema = Convert.ToDateTime(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["fechaSistema"]);
```

In the configuration file:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key ="fechaSistema" value = "2013-05-28"/>
  </appSettings>
```

The code that executes the procedures looks like this:

```
        private static DataTable _retrieveDataTable(string procedure, List<string> args, params object[] values)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            conexionSql(cn, cm);
            cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cm.CommandText = "HARDCODERS."+procedure;
            _loadSqlCommand(args, values, cm);
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(dr);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

        finally
        {
            if (cn != null)
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
private static void _loadSqlCommand(List<string> args, object[] values, SqlCommand cm)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Count; i++)
    {
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue(args[i], values[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

And the method that calls this just does:

```
SqlConnector.retrieveDataTable("getTop5ClientesConMasPuntosAcumulados", Globals.getFechaSistema());
```

Comment: The c# code would be relevant.

Comment: ***WHAT*** database (and which version thereof)?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you're trying to pass an nvarchar for the parameter.

Comment: No code means all we can say is somewhere it's trying to convert some string to a datetime.

Comment: Sorry guys. Just editted with more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
private static void _loadSqlCommand(List<string> args, object[] values, SqlCommand cm)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Count; i++)
    {
        // This line:
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue(args[i], values[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Your `.ToString()` call forces .NET to tell SQL Server that the parameter you're sending in is a `String` type and SQL is unable to convert the string (`nvarchar`) to `datetime` directly. If you remove the `.ToString()` call, it should work as expected.

```
private static void _loadSqlCommand(List<string> args, object[] values, SqlCommand cm)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Count; i++)
    {
        // This should work:
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue(args[i], values[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I am so stupid lol. But what about if I send an integer, will it automatically parse it?

Comment: Qué va, no te preocupes. ;)

Comment: Yes, it should always send the appropriate SqlDbType.